# Installing svgcairo on windows

Tags: haskell, cabal, cairo

I have managed to install cairo, but when I run `cabal install svgcairo` I get the following error:

```
setup.exe: The pkg-config package librsvg-2.0 version >=2.16.0 is required but it could not be found.
```

I'm on windows 8 x64, with cabal version 1.16.02 and ghc 7.6.3.

Answer (score 1):

You need to install librsvg in a location that ghc can find first.  Check out http://librsvg.sourceforge.net/download/ for downloads, but you might have to build it from source yourself, which is beyond the scope of this answer.  Then just make sure that wherever you've installed the library is on your path and that `pkg-config` can find it, and you should be good to go.